# ByteBuffer allocate and allocateDirect

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I wondering when there is no memory available does allocateDirect and allocate from ByteBuffer will return null pointer or sth else ? (I was unable to find it in java docs). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For both methods, the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is thrown when there is no virtual memory to spare.

Answer (score 2):

ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() is limited by the `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` for HotSpot. When this limit is reach you get an OutOfMemoryError.